# How to extract value from SmartStore aggregate function query

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I'm sure the solution must be quite simple, but I can't figure out how to extract the value from a SmartStore Aggregate function query using mobile sdk 7.2 in Swift.

Here's my query:

```swift
        let sql = "select sum({inventory:qtyOnHand}) from {inventory} where {inventory:location} = '1234'"
        if let querySepc = QuerySpec.buildSmartQuerySpec(smartSql: sql , pageSize: 1){
            let store = SmartStore.shared(withName: SmartStore.defaultStoreName)!

            let qryResult: [Any] = try store.query(using: querySepc, startingFromPageIndex: 0)
            print("qryResult = \(qryResult)") 
            //prints qryResult = [<__NSArrayM 0x600003d88f60>(432)]
            print(type(of: qryResult))
            //prints Array<Any>            

            let record = qryResult[0]

            print("record = \(record)")
            //prints record = (432)
            print("type of record = \(type(of:record))")
            //prints type of record = __NSArrayM
```

I've tried casting qryResult[0] to [String:Any], [Int:Any] any of these variations just sets the the record constant to nil

I tried accessing the value from the record constant via subscript and that failed with: "Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts"

Comment: Is this question is even related to Salesforce?

Comment: @ArnoldJr., it is related to the Salesforce Mobile SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use SmartSQL, you get back an array of arrays.
So if you do:

```
select a,b,c from x
```

You should get back something like:

```
[[a1,b1,c1], [a2,b2,c3], ...]
```

Therefore if you do:

```
select sum(a) from x
```

You should get back something like:

```
[[the-sum]]
```

Example in Swift

```
let query = QuerySpec.buildSmartQuerySpec(smartSql: "SELECT count(*) FROM {\(SOUP_NAME)}", pageSize: 1)!
let result = try self.store.query(using:query, startingFromPageIndex:0);
let count = (result[0] as! [Int])[0];
```

For an example, check out https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/blob/master/libs/SmartStore/SmartStoreTests/SFSmartSqlTests.m#L220

For a Swift example, check out https://github.com/wmathurin/GlobalStoreTester/blob/master/common/ViewController70.swift#L97

Comment: Hi Wolfgang thank you for the input!  I must be accessing the data incorrectly? it seems like I am only getting back an array of Any [Any] instead of an array of arrays [[Any]].  When I print out the result of the query “select count({contacts:Id}) from {contacts}”, this is what I get in the output window of Xcode 10.3: 
[<__NSArrayM 0x60000334c930>(
1
)
]

If I assign subscript 0 of the query result to a variable I am then left with an Any with no subscripts per the compiler.  If I try and cast the Any to an Int it is nil.

Comment: I added a swift example in my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, that worked.  Very much appreciate the assistance!